# Extending Object's class methods - correct way

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am looking for correct way to add "static" methods (class level methods) into Object and all its children in JavaScript.

I am trying to do:

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... };  
// actually I need only class level method
// but it creates instance method too
```

I am getting wanted:

```
function MyClass() {};
var mc = new MyClass();

mc.myMethod();
```

But I am getting also unwanted:

```
mc.someProperty = 'val';

for (var k in mc) {
  console.log(k);
}

// => myMethod (this is unwanted)
// => someProperty
```

How to add only class method into Object and all it's children without adding of instance method's?

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys. A `for..in` is no longer needed...

Comment: Those are called instance methods. A static function would be `Object.staticFn = function () { ... };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, your loop has to be altered:

```
for (var k in mc) {
    if (mc.hasOwnProperty(k)) {// Ignores inherit methods/properties
       console.log(k);
    }
}
```

An alternative solution is by using the [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method to make the element not-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(mc.prototype, 'myMethod', {
    value: function() {
        // Logic here
    },
    enumerable: false, // <--- Property unreachable through for(k in mc)
    writable: true,    // <-- Optional, default false
    configurable: true // <-- Optional, default false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a common recommendation not to pollute `Object.prototype`, because it will affect *all* objects. Booleans, numbers, strings, arrays, functions – everything.

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function () { /* ... */ }
typeof ''.myMethod // "function"
```

If you want all of your constructor functions (like `MyClass`) to have this "class-method", a somewhat lesser evil might be to add the method to the `Function.prototype` object.

```
Function.prototype.myMethod = function () { /* ... */ }
```

With this approach instances of your constructors won't have `myMethod` in their prototype chain, because they aren’t functions.

However, you’ll still have this method on all function objects:

```
typeof (function () {}).myMethod // "function"
```

Not that anyone would often enumerate properties of functions, anyway.

Overall, `myMethod` would be a prototype method on the language level and a static method on your own constructors’ level.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? If you want "static" methods, then they would have no real use for the `this` parameter. And if that is the case, why not just create a one off object that houses all the methods you need?

```
var MyStaticMethods = {
     foo: function() {},
     bar: function() {}
};
```

Then just call `MyStaticMethods.foo()`.

Also keep in mind generally touching the `Object` prototype is not recommended.

You can add the methods directly to `Object` itself:

```
Object.foo = function() { ... }
```

But this does not mean `MyClass.foo` will exist, you must always call it with `Object.foo()`, and with that being the case the one off object above is a better approach.

Comment: I need this behavior for core of my framework.
I am trying to do gently touch of Object's prototype - this experience helps me to learn language more deeply.